# How to reference a theme attribute in a style?

Tags: android, styles, themes

I've got a following problem. I want to customize appearance of row in a list, but exception is thrown during inflating.

piece of code in style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.Main">     
    <item name="item_shadowColor">#000000</item>        
</style>
<style name="item_label">    
    <item name="android:shadowColor">?attr/item_shadowColor</item>        
</style>
```

attr.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="item_shadowColor" format="color" />
</resources>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/title"
        style="@style/item_label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the exception

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    at ru.mts.goodok.adapter.CategoryListAdapter.getView(CategoryListAdapter.java:30)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2052)
    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1820)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:732)
    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1673)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1882)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11425)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4232)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:925)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11425)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4232)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11425)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4232)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11425)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4232)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11425)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4232)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1516)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2505)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
    ... 39 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "?2130771972"
    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
    at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
    at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java:123)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getInt(TypedArray.java:254)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:829)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:489)
    ... 42 more
```

What am I doing wrong and how could I solve this problem?

Comment: ?attr/item_shadowColor remove this and give your own color.

Comment: ?attr/item_shadowColor couldn't be removed because it sets color for different themes

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem has been solved. I used application context to create adapter, when I changed context to activity the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 5):

Try to create the `themes.xml` file and add the below lines in it.

**Themes.xml**

```
<style name="Theme">
   <item name="item_shadowColor">@style/item_label</item>
</style>
```

**attrs.xml**
Change the the `format="reference"` in your `attrs.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="item_shadowColor" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme.Main">     
    <item name="item_shadowColor">#000000</item>        
</style>

<style name="item_label">    
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#F240FF</item>        
</style>
```

Then after define your style to the TextView as below:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@id/title"
    style="@style/item_label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```