# Android: Custom colors in styles not working

Tags: android, xml, styles, themes

I have an attrs.xml file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <attr name="butBackColor" format="reference|color" />
</resources>
```

Styles.xml contains:

```
<style name="GreyButtonTheme" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
  <item name="butBackColor">#3D3D3D</item>
</style>
```

I have custom_button.xml which contains a drawable selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
...
        <item android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp" android:bottom="5dp">              
          <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/butGreyBack" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
          </shape>
          </item>
```

Finally, I have a layout which contains a Button which I want to use my style with:

The code snippets above work fine for me - but when I change:

```
<solid android:color="@color/butGreyBack" />
```

to:

```
<solid android:color="?butBackColor" />
```

..then I get an "Error inflating class " exception. Why is the custom_button.xml selector failing? What do I need to do to get the ?butBackColor attribute to work?

The reason I have implemented it this way is that I would like to use different styles (colours) for different sets of buttons.

Here is the project which may be of use to somebody who wants a file browser dialog box:

[FileBrowserTestDlg](https://www.mediafire.com/?lsqjibcedlmfcfj)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format for referencing the attribute is

```
?[<package_name>:][<resource_type>/]<resource_name>
```

**change this:**

```
<solid android:color="?butBackColor" />
```

**to:**

```
<solid android:color="?attr/butBackColor" />
```

SparkyNZ wrote: The answer to this question is at the very end of the comments. The above lines didn't actually solve the problem. What I did learn is that it is not possible with the current Android SDK to use custom attributes within shape/drawable XML files. They work fine in View definitions, but not shape/drawables.

Comment: Thanks. I changed it to <solid android:color="?attr/butBackColor" /> but I still have the same problem. If I change it back to <solid android:color="@color/butGreyBack" /> then it works - just tried that in case there were other offending lines.

Comment: Also tried full package name <solid android:color="?com.example.filebrowsertest:attr/butBackColor" /> and didn't like that either.

Comment: @SparkyNZ try to change attrs.xml to attr.xml

Comment: @ Rod_Algonquin: No luck. I renamed it from attr.xml to attrs.xml when following a tutorial earlier. Renamed it back and still ain't working. Do I need a namespace line or something? Shouldn't if the entire package is specified though. attr.xml is in my 'values' folder by the way.

Comment: I renamed butBackColor to but_back_color and that didn't work either (had problems with uppercase in the past with drawables).

Comment: @SparkyNZ follow what he did here the last answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399284/how-to-reference-a-theme-attribute-in-a-style

Comment: There could be a problem with your activity which creates this layout not the layout itself. Check that out and if you can post it here pls.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin: I tried adding a themes.xml and I find that I can use ?butSelectBackColor as the android:textColor within the Button definition - that works as expected - but I cannot use ?butSelectBackColor in the custom_button.xml drawable.

Comment: @SparkyNZ that is because you specify it as a theme for button not a thheme for shapes

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin: Sorry I don't understand what you mean. Time for me to pick up kids so will have to revisit later. I have attached a link to the project if you are keen to have a look (please). Its the custom_button.xml file that I want to use the ?ButSelectBackColor attributes etc.

Comment: @Boggartfly: Thanks - I've put a link to the project if you are keen on having a look.

Comment: @SparkyNZ remove the parent.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin: I have tried removing parent="AppTheme". All it does is make the app start up with a black background instead of white and it still has an exception just the same. Were you referring to a different parent definition?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin: This SO post says what I want to achieve is not possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952181/using-attribute-to-modify-a-drawable-element-color

Comment: @SparkyNZ As I thought because style are meant for style tag for a view.

Comment: Thanks! This is the solution that also worked for me!